# MVC PartialView()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

_GenreList is a partialView  When i call the update action just partialView appears an the url like that

localhost:1234/Index/GenreUpdate

i wanna see the partialView in the index view  like that

localhost:1234/Index/

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GenreUpdate(Genre genre)
    {
        db.Entry(genre).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return PartialView("_GenreList", db.Genres.ToList().ToPagedList(1, 5));
    }
```

I used @Html.Action(_GenreList) in indexView but , when i call the update action it doesn't go IndexView
What should i do ?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Its Child-action and it takes root into a pool, also bypass httpcontext object and rout system dont register it in querystring object.

Comment: Not only is this almost completely unreadable, how does this even remotely answer the question?